# How to subtract two columns from each other in SQL (PostgresSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an orders table with 4 columns. There are three important columns -

dateordered
orderstatus - either "completed" or "returned"
orders - the number of orders put in

I want to find the sum of each month's completed orders and subtract the returned orders for a remaining total per month. This is my code so far:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', dateordered), SUM(orders) - (
    SELECT SUM(orders)
    FROM c_orders
    WHERE orderstatus = 'returned'
)
FROM c_orders
WHERE orderstatus = 'complete'
GROUP BY 1
```

I know the main body of the query works correctly to pull the completed orders by month. The problem is the subquery - I don't know how to specify the sum of returned orders by month. So right now this query is subtracting the sum of all returned orders throughout the entire dataset without specifying month.

Is there a better way to do this? TIA

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', dateordered) as yyyymm,
       SUM(CASE WHEN orderstatus = 'complete' THEN orders
                WHEN orderstatus = 'returned' THEN - orders
                ELSE 0
           END) 
FROM c_orders
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Bonus q - if I wanted to then do a percent change calculation from one month to the other, starting with August, how could I do that?

Comment: I couldn't fit the answer in a comment. Please post as new question.